# Parallel Matrix Calculations

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix, parallel-processing

so I am trying to parallize my matrix in such a manner that the matrix rows are divided by the number of threads provided and they calculate the rows assigned to them. The kicker is that the size of the matrix will be decreased by every iteration.

So within the main matrix, I will be doing calculations for a submatrix and dividing that matrix between threads.

To make this easier to visualize, I'll provide some pseudo code.

```
for (i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++)
{
     begin = (((matrixSize - i)/numOfThreads) * threadNum + i);
     end = (((matrixSize - i)/numOfThreads) * (threadNum + 1) + i - 1);

        for(j = begin ; j < end; j++) {
            // get which row to calculate within the main matrix
            for (k = i + 1; k < nsize; k++) {
                // calculations for the columns
            }
         }    
}
```

The issue is setting the values of the begin and end. Because the size of the matrix may be prime number, say 991, the first "block" of calculations will have to do an extra row.

Comment: What is the calculation? Might not be worth making this parallel! Thought about using the GPU?

Comment: I am making the gaussian elimination parallel, it is to test to see performance enhancements - for school!

Comment: Thought about worker threads. Going too parallel will not have a good benefit hit. Try to limit it to the number of CPUs.

Comment: Yup, we are working on a 24 CPU system, I plan to see how the increase of threads and increase of CPUs will affect performance and if it is worth it at all.

Comment: @EdHeal what sense does a GPU make if you aren't even sure the computation is worth running in parallel?

Comment: @MatrixQQ multithreaded LU is a solved problem. See Google scholar for details.

Comment: GPU is a different beast than a CPU. It is able to process the same instruction an different data. Read up about CUDA

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is setting the values of the begin and end. Because the size of the matrix may be prime number, say 991, the first "block" of calculations will have to do an extra row.

You can calculate the number of rows per thread as

```
rowSize = (matrixSize - i)/numOfThreads
```

That leaves you potentially with some left-over rows.  You can determine how many are left over as

```
extraRows = (matrixSize - i) % numOfThreads
```

You can assign the extra rows to one of the threads, or divide them equally between some of your threads.

Comment: Do you know how I can dynamically assign those extra threads to the remaining rows?